# Swap character pointer in function

Tags: c

This C code below is an infinite loop. However, if we replace `void hello()` to `main()` it works perfectly.

Why is that and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void charSwap(char** a, char** b){
    char *c = *a;
         *a = *b;
         *b = c;
}
void hello(){
    char **a,**b;
    int i;
    printf("A = ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    getchar();
    printf("B = ");
    scanf("%c",&b);
    getchar();
    if(a>b) charSwap(&a,&b);
    for (i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        printf("%c : %d , %X\n",i,i,i);
    }
}
int main(){
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't the compiler not complain/warn at all?

Comment: Yes.
- warning:  assignment makes interger frome pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
- warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: And consider reading [this](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) about going into 3 (or more) levels of indirection.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&a);` really?

Comment: @M.M Yes, I'm newbie learning C.

Comment: @J...S Thanks. I'll read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code that invoke undefined behavior. 
For instance -

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

`scanf` expects a `char*` as the second argument with `%c`. But you are passing a `char***`.

Same with the function call to `charSwap(&a,&b);`. The function expects `char**` as you have defined. But you are passing `char***` again.

If I understand your code correctly, you need to store a `char` only and don't really need `char**`s.

So a simple fix would be to replace

```
char **a,**b;
```

with

```
char a, b;
```

Here is a [working demo](https://ideone.com/v8XZwm) with the fix.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found my solve to answer this question.
Just remove one star at `void charSwap(char** a)` to `void hello(char* a)`

```
void charSwap(char* a, char* b){
char *c = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = c;
```

}

and in `void hello()`  at `char a,b;`

```
void hello(){
   char a,b;
}
```